# Proof by cases - discrete math

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have some question in proof techniques that is very difficult for me to solve..

The question is:

I need to prove by the **cases** technique that:

**If a,b ∈Z, and a=b³, there is c ∈Z so a=9*c or a=9*c+1 or a=9*c-1.**

I thought about it a lot but i have no any direction how to solve it..need your help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider these $3$ cases: $b$ is a multiple of $3$, $b$ is of the form $3k+1$ and $b$ is of the form $3k-1$.

Comment: but b could be also 3k+2 no?

Comment: Since $3k+2=3(k+1)-1$, there is no defference between the case $3k+2$ and the case $3k-1$.

Comment: ok, but the most difficult for me is to understand what to do with "c", should i try to express "c" by "b"?

Comment: No. You should try to compute $(3k)^3$, $(3k+1)^3$, and $(3k-1)^3$.

Comment: for the case _b = 3k_, i get _a = 9k^3_ from this i should understand that _c = k^3_ but how c is connected to the a and b?

Comment: In the case $b=3k$, you got $a=9k^2$, which means that $a=9\left(\frac b3\right)^2$.

Comment: but (3k)^3 is not 9k^2

Comment: ok i understand that i can express a in this way a=9(b/3)^3 but how can i say that c = (b/3)^3 so i will get a=9*c ?

Comment: My mistake: in the case $b=3k$, you got $a=9k^3$. Actually, since $a=b^3$, you should have obtained that $a=27k^3$. But then$$a=9\times\left(3\times\left(\frac k3\right)^3\right).$$

Comment: It follows from my previous comment, that if $b$ is a multiple of $3$ and if you take $c=3\times\left(\frac k3\right)^3$, then $a=9\times c$ (and $c\in\mathbb N$).

Comment: ok now i understand that i didn't approach the question correctly, thanks you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The cases are: $b=3k$, $b=3k+1$ and $b=3k-1$. Then you should express the $c$ as follows:
$$a=(3k)^3=9\cdot \underbrace{3k^2}_{c},\\
a=(3k+1)^3=9(\underbrace{3k^3+3k^2+k}_{c})+1,$$
Can you figure out the last case?